# XmlNode returns in OuterXml unexpected namespace xmlns

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode

I have XmlNode object with next attributes:

[image]

But when i call OuterXml Property i have all those attributes and also **xmlns** attribute with namespace included. But i dont wath to have this namespace there! How can i set to node properties not to show in OuterXml this attribute xmlns with namespace?

I need this clean outerxml because i use this xml in documents which already contains such namespace and i really dont need to set it in xml node.

Comment: Why are you using `OuterXml` for that? You should just move the whole `XmlElement` to the document you are creating.

Comment: Because nodes is transferred from one system to other like text (But root documents is same) So i use OuterXML.

Comment: So, you're transferring XML elements that are not whole documents from one system to another? If that's the case, I think you shouldn't do that.

Comment: A: what does the image show? (because it doesn't really illustrate anything about namespaces), and B: if the element *is* part of a fragment in a namespace, how could it be omitted? (meaning: it would be *correct* to include a namespace)

Comment: it shows that i have no xmlns attribute there.

Comment: @Evgeny: nodes have a (default) namespace always. Your namespace manager controls what prefixes (if any) are to be emitted. Note that if you are using Xml nodes from more than 1 namespace, you are bound to have xmlns declarations